# X-FRAME-OPTIONS allow-from a top-level domain, and all subsequent sub-domains

Tags: x-frame-options

I'm in a conundrum, and could really use some help...

I'm having difficulty trying to find information regarding how to enable a site -that already has X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN encoded- to be loaded into an iframe from a couple of specific domains (i.e. domain.com would be the common TLD).  The issue is, that although this would be quite simple to do -using X-FRAME-OPTIONS: ALLOW-FROM http://domain.com-, if that were the only domain which would ever have a need to access the target site via an iframe.  In reality however, I actually need to figure out how to set it up for (currently) three sub-domains -with the possibility of allowing from even more in the future- of the original TLD (i.e. example1.domain.com, example2.domain.com, and example3.domain.com), to be able to access the site while loaded inside the intended iframe.  The only info I've been able to find regarding this issue so far is quite a bit outdated, and says that there is NO POSSIBLE WAY to allow a wildcard reference (or any other form of multiple domain reference) for a particular domain that would also apply to it's subsequent sub-domains (or anything along those lines) that seems to be effective at both functioning as intended and also preventing 'Clickjackin' by malicious individuals from occurring.  I was hoping that someone more knowledgeable (and better versed in X-FRAME-OPTIONS) than myself might actually be able to offer me a feasible resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ALLOW-FROM doesn't even have proper browser support yet, http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-frame-options

Comment: @CBroe ... I know (kinda sad that they haven't resolved that yet really).  The site isn't a site that I'm hosting, but my clients in their area have a need to reference it.  So, here I am trying to figure out how to help them maintain what they wanted in their coding, meanwhile trying to facilitate the needs of my clients.

Answer (score 1):

If you can entertain approaches outside of X-Frame-Options, consider creating a server-to-server API that can be called to access the content in question, and then allow it to be displayed without requiring framing.

That is, instead of ClientSite containing an IFRAME referencing the FramedPage which does the page assembly *within the web browser*, ClientSite calls an API on the backend to get the content directly from you and inserts the content into the page *on the server* **before** delivering the page to the user's web browser.

This gives you substantial flexibility. You could require an API key, apply basic server-to-server IP address whitelisting, or whatever suits, to prevent unwanted callers of your API.